# How to connect to Postgres on Cloud SQL using the Python Standard Environment on App Engine

Tags: python, postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine-python

I have an app that uses the Python Standard Environment on App Engine. I tried, but failed, to find instructions to connect to Postgres on Cloud SQL.

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine), under "App Engine standard environment to Cloud SQL", I only see instructions for Java.

Is it really the case that there is no way to connect to Postgres on Cloud SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL is currently only available to GAE Flexible environments and GAE Standard running on Java 8. Python on GAE Standard is not yet supported for PostgreSQL. See [FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/faq#gaeconnect-pg) and [supported languages here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine#gaev1-csqlv2).

Comment: Is there any eta that you know of for PostgreSQL support on GAE Standard w/ Python? I would love it!

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7, you can use [pg8000](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000), but it lacks some features and, in my experience, a little unstable.

For Python 3.7, you can use [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/). Seems that the docs examples are for MySQL and not for PostgreSQL, but you can see them [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-app-engine).